# Importing a .csv file in C++: crash

Tags: c++, csv

I'm trying to import a .csv file into a vector that contains all the file's lines, here is my function :

```
vector<string> ReadCsvFileContent(const string file){
  vector<string> buffer;
  ifstream data;
  data.open(file.c_str());
  string line;
  while(getline(data, line, ', ')){
      buffer.push_back(line);
  }
  data.close();
  return buffer;
}
```

My file looks like this :

```
nbElements: 5
index, largeur
0, 740, 
1, 742, 
2, 746, 
3, 756, 
4, 749,
```

But it does not seem to work, it suddenly crashes... someone's got a hint please?

Comment: Is this all of your code?   Why aren't you returning a value from `ReadCsvFileContent`?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my message... it returns an error like 'no matching function for call to 'getline(std::ifstream&, std::__cxx11::string&, int)'

Comment: Then you need to post a [mcve].  What you are now stating is a compiler error, not a "crash".

Comment: So was the original code before you edited it the actual code you were running?  If so, then I am going to restore it to the original, so that the answer given makes sense.  If you edited your code based on the comment or answer, then that isn't the way it works here.  Before posting code in a question, make sure it is the *actual* code you're running, and not a hastily typed in approximation of the code you're running.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with you code is the`', '` is not a charector and the argument you need to provide is a charector. The easiest fix for this is:

```
while(getline(data, line, ',')){
    buffer.push_back(line.substr(1));
}
```

Hope this helps.